# GSON deserialize every object (Date, Float, Integer) to string

Tags: android, json, gson

i would like to deserialize string

```
{
  "foo":5,
  "bar":"03.10.01"
}
```

I want to deserialize it to Map which will contain only Strings.
Using sample code gives me Integer in place of "5" and java.Util.Date instead of date String.

```
Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
map = (Map<Object, Object>) gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), map.getClass());
```

I don't know what will be in JSON, that's why i'm parsing it into Map

@reactivemobile
It's true but what if JSON is like:

As i said, I don't know what will be in JSON, it can look like:

```
{
  "array": [
    {
      "eggs": 5,
      "bb": "03.10.01"
    }
  ],
  "foo": 5,
  "bar": "03.10.01"
}
```

Giving this with Map will create Map that contains ArrayList, foo, bar. In ArrayList there will be LinkedTreeMap that will contain "eggs" and "bb".

So your answer is correct, but not in the case where JSON can have dynamic structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Map<String, String> map
```

To force the values to be Strings

Comment: Nevermind I used org.json.JSONObject, it exactly does what i need. - gives any value as a String.